# yellow icon for wamp server

Tags: wampserver

the icon of wamp server is yellow, I tried in:

1.Open file httpd.conf through wamp tray icon

Find:

```
# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change to:

```
# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

no change!

2.left click the wamp icon > Put Online

no change, still online put yellow icon --> locall host not work

3.apache --> service --> start service --> not work
4.apache --> service --> test port 80 -->

your port actually used by:
server : Microsoft

I don't know what to do?

Comment: i trIED starting wamp before skype

nOT WORKED

Answer (score 6):

Ok, i figured this out. What is happening is Skype is blocking port 80. So, you have to do the following:

1. Right click on skype.
2. Click on quit and allow it to quit.
3. Left click on the Wamp Server icon
4. Click Start all services.
5. Thats it!
   If you want to use skype, do all of the steps (1-4) then start skype again.

Answer (score 4):

It's my own problem and solveed it.
click start and type servicesp-> open it and stop it ( at the r8 side).
click on the yellow icon and got  apache--> service--> test port 80--> if it's available,
then again go to apache --> service and --> install service

restart all services by clicking wamp icon and then you will find green

Comment: It worked for me as well!
I guess i need to save this instructions somewhere, I wasn't aware I had to do this to make it work!

Answer (score 2):

i did face this complex and i did tried all the solution to make wamp server go to green , but it did not work , every thing at all , but , when i click on test port 80 on apache , it gives your port 80 is used by http/api2.0 . and from here i found the answer from a contributor in ther web site
http://theandystratton.com/2012/wampapache-broken-from-microsoft-httpapi-2-0-using-port-80
 , here is the solution :

Turning off Microsoft HTTP/API 2.0

1. Open your Control Panel (Start > Control Panel)
2. Change the view setting from Category to Small or Large Icons
3. Open Administrative Tools
4. Open Services
5. Find “Web Deployment Service Agent” in the list
6. Right click and choose Properties
7. Click Stop
8. Change it’s Start Up value to “Manual”
9. Hit Apply/OK to save the changes
10. Go to WAMP and restart all services

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue that fixed mine on VirtualBox.  For some reason the WAMP installer never installed the service.  To fix it, left click on the yellow wamp icon in your task bar area, select Apache>>Service>>Install Service then follow the instructions in the DOS screen.

Next go back to Apache>>Service>> and select "Start/Resume Service"

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **WAMP 2.1**
I also tried each and everything, but install WAMP 2.1, refrain from 2.2,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.1/

Have a gr8 time

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Left click the wamp icon, go to apache and then test port 80.
2. If it shows apache then it is working fine and if it shows MicrosoftApi etc. then go to services --> search for web deployment agent service and stop it.
3. Restart the wamp and hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to find out the wampserver's errors

1. Go to Control Panel -> Event Viewer
2. Find "Apache Service" in "Summary of Administrative Events", then double click on it
3. View errors and fix them.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There are many obscure things that can cause this, in my case I had enabled the PHP zip extension, it caused the yellow icon and the services were not started. With the services not started it wouldn't let me disable the extension, had to manually edit the php.ini and comment it out.  Then wamp started fine.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install WAMP and try to turn off WAMP before switching off machine and don't force stop while turning off, if WAMP is on and you will not deal with this problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was using a different port rather than 80.

1. Left click over the "W" icon
2. Select Apache > Use a port other than 80
3. 8080 worked fine for me

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on "allow VirtualHost local ip's others than 127.*" in wamp settings.

its working fine with (green tray icon)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I click on the yellow icon and then click on start all services, try it may it will help u.

Enjoy your tech journey ;)

Answer (score 0):

**HOW TO FIX ANY PROBLEM WITH WAMP-SERVER:**

Go to **Control Panel -> Event Viewer**
Find **"Apache Service"** in **"Summary of Administrative Events"**, then double click on it.

**View errors and fix them.**

MY ERROR WAS:
MySQL was not working, mariaDB was blocking the port 3306. I had to go to services and end the service. After that I installed again MySQL service from left click menu (wamp icon). And then I Started All Services and it was green again :)

Cheers @Tin Nguyen

Comment: log might be a way to understand the issue, but it will not solve the problem for the user (his problem is apache not having its port available to bind)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix it by restart the apache service like this

**Step1: install service**

**Step 2:** then again go to the same menu (like as image) and select **"Start/Resume Service"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me, I had `the code execution cannot proceed because vcruntime140.dll` error in the installation process and fixed by installing Microsoft VC packages downloaded from [this URL](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

but after that, the yellow icon not fixed by doing every possible way, **it was fixed just by reinstalling wamp!**

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, click on wamp icon => apache => service => install service

however avoid installing 64 bit wamp, sometimes it throws dll errors, i recommend Laragon instead