# Wamp Server Staying on Yellow (Windows 8.1 64 bit)

Tags: wamp

I am trying to run a WAMP server and it stays on Yellow every time, since Apache wont run. I tried Installing the Service, I changed the port, I changed the settings on my Skype, which even when not running, it still doesn't work. None of the methods I found online works. I am running a 64 bit computer with Windows 8.1.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used WAMP, but when I ran into that problem, it was usually after changing something in the httpd.conf.  I would also invite you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652115/yellow-icon-for-wamp-server

Comment: _A look at the Apache error log_ or the _Windows Event Viewer_ should show you the error. Have you installed all the Microsoft C/C++ Runtime libraries required to run WAMPServer? [See this post on the WAMPServer forum for a list and a downloadable install for all of these libraries](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Comment: This is my error code: 
`[Sun Nov 20 00:09:03.155212 2016] [auth_digest:error] [pid 10708:tid 432] (OS 6851)The operation could not be completed because the volume is dirty. Please run chkdsk and try again.  : AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled
[Sun Nov 20 00:09:03.155212 2016] [:emerg] [pid 10708:tid 432] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
`